# ALAssetsGroup setAssetsFilter to get both photos and videos in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios4

I am using ALAssetsGroup to show photos and videos.

The ALAssetsGroup is have a method called

```
- (void)setAssetsFilter:(ALAssetsFilter *)filter;
```

using this filer you can either filter photos

```
[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]
```

or videos

```
[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]
```

But I want to get both photos and videos. I didn't find any method wherein after filtering I can add both of them.

Waiting for your reply

Thanks in advance

===================EDIT======================================

I saw the below Asset types in the document:-

// Asset types

```
extern NSString *const ALAssetTypePhoto  // The asset is a photo

extern NSString *const ALAssetTypeVideo   // The asset is a video

extern NSString *const ALAssetTypeUnknown   // The asset's type cannot be determined.
It could be a sound file, a video or photo file that we don't know about, or something else. This is possible only for assets imported from a camera onto the device.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`setAssetsFilter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsGroup_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsGroup/setAssetsFilter%3a):

I would emphasize the sentence in italics:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method sets the filter the group; it does not execute the filter.
>   The filter is applied when you invoke numberOfAssets or enumerate the
>   contents.
>
> If you don’t set the filter, or set it to nil, the enumeration returns
>   all the assets in the group.
>
> **Special Considerations**
>
> ***Only one filter is active at a time.*** Any enumeration currently in
>   flight continues to completion using the previous filter.

To me this means you can't currently do a filter that has both "videos" and "photos" together.

But then again, now that I think more about it: the only assets that exist are videos & photos, period.

Why not simply enumerate all assets (via ALAssetsFilter's [`allAssets`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/ALAssetsFilter/allAssets))?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have edited my question plz have a look at it.

Comment: I still think `allAssets` is the way to go.  That's what I do in my own apps where I want the users to select both photos and videos.